# Fix Index out of bounds for array?

Tags: java, arrays, 2d, maze

I am creating a maze game using console of eclipse. I am trying to move a player, and save the players new position so I can move him in another direction. However, every time I try to move the player, I get Index ___ out of bounds for length 5 (usually -1 or 5). It is skipping over the entire array, and I am unsure how to fix it.

When ran, it prints the following

P . . ! .

. . . . .

. . . ! .

! ! . T .

! . ! ! .

Please select one of the following:

Press 1 to move up.

Press 2 to move down.

Press 3 to move left.

Press 4 to move right.

Press 0 to stop playing the game.

I only listed one movement, but the rest are the same, with interchanging variables. Every option returns Index out of bounds. And I was suggested to create a 'check' system but that doesn't solve the problem. It just runs the program without allowing any movements, because every movement returns out of bounds. I believe it has something to do with the line

```
mazeStructure[vxTemp][vyTemp] = mazeStructure[i][k-1];
```

Either that or something to do with the for conditions. If someone could provide a fix that would be greatly appreciated.

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
int rowsTotal = 5;
int columnsTotal = 5;
int vxTemp = 0;
int vyTemp = 0;
String[][] mazeStructure =  {
        {"P",".",".","!","."},
        {".",".",".",".","."},
        {".",".",".","!","."},
        {"!","!",".","T","."},
        {"!",".","!","!","."},
};

 boolean won = false;
while (won == false){
    for (int a = 0; a < rowsTotal; a++){
        for (int b = 0; b < columnsTotal; b++){
            System.out.print(mazeStructure[a][b]);
            System.out.print(" ");
    }
        System.out.print("\n");
  }


    System.out.printf("\n");
    System.out.println("Please select one of the following:");
    System.out.println("Press 1 to move up.");
    System.out.println("Press 2 to move down.");
    System.out.println("Press 3 to move left.");
    System.out.println("Press 4 to move right.");
    System.out.println("Press 0 to stop playing the game.");
    int choice = input.nextInt();
    int a = 0;

   
    if (choice == 1 && a >= 0 && a < columnsTotal){
    for (int i = 0; i < rowsTotal; i++){
        for (int k = 0; k < columnsTotal; k++){
        if (mazeStructure[vxTemp][vyTemp-1].equals("!") == false && mazeStructure[i][k].equals(mazeStructure[vxTemp][vyTemp])){
                    mazeStructure[vxTemp][vyTemp] = ".";
                    mazeStructure[vxTemp][vyTemp-1] = "P";
                    mazeStructure[vxTemp][vyTemp] = mazeStructure[i][k-1];
       }else if (mazeStructure[vxTemp][vyTemp-1] == "!"){
                    System.out.println("Move isn't allowed.");
       }else {
        continue;}
```

Comment: Share me your error screen

Comment: @Uzair Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 5 out of bounds for length 5
 at trest.main(trest.java:89)             This happens on the "down" function, which is vyTemp+1 instead of vyTemp-1.

Answer (score 0):

In the line `if (mazeStructure[vxTemp][vyTemp-1].equals("!") == false && mazeStructure[i][k].equals(mazeStructure[vxTemp][vyTemp])){` you try to access `mazeStructure` at `[vxTemp][vyTemp-1]`. You initialize `vyTemp` at 0 and it doesnt change before this point. You start that loop with trying `vyTemp - 1` which will be -1. That will be out of bounds for your array.

You do that same with variable `k` within your loop. The first time around `k` will be zero. So all though `k - 1` existing is ok, you can't try to access any array at some -1 index.

Comment: That makes sense, but for the "down" option, I have vyTemp+1, and I get index 5 out of bounds for length 5. This is the same for each choice (up, down, left, right).

Comment: Arrays are zero indexed. Meaning you access the first element of an array with array[0]. If we start at zero and have a length of 5, our end ```index``` is 4. In other words, although the array ```length``` is 5, we access that element at array[4] (since we started at 0). That's why 5 is out of bounds.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem is `vyTemp-1` in this line

`if (mazeStructure[vxTemp][vyTemp-1].equals("!") == false && mazeStructure[i][k].equals(mazeStructure[vxTemp][vyTemp])){`

The value of vyTemp is 0 initially

Comment: Makes sense, but this is the same for everything across the board. For example, my 'down' option, which is vyTemp+1, returns an index 5 out of bounds for length 5.

Answer (score 0):

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
int rowsTotal = 5;
int columnsTotal = 5;
int vxTemp = 0;
int vyTemp = 0;
String[][] mazeStructure =  {
        {"P",".",".","!","."},
        {".",".",".",".","."},
        {".",".",".","!","."},
        {"!","!",".","T","."},
        {"!",".","!","!","."},
};

 boolean won = false;
while (won == false){
    for (int a = 0; a < rowsTotal; a++){
        for (int b = 0; b < columnsTotal; b++){
            System.out.print(mazeStructure[a][b]);
            System.out.print(" ");
    }
        System.out.print("\n");
  }


    System.out.printf("\n");
    System.out.println("Please select one of the following:");
    System.out.println("Press 1 to move up.");
    System.out.println("Press 2 to move down.");
    System.out.println("Press 3 to move left.");
    System.out.println("Press 4 to move right.");
    System.out.println("Press 0 to stop playing the game.");
    int choice = input.nextInt();
    int a = 0;

   
    if (choice == 1 && a >= 0 && a < columnsTotal){
    for (int i = 0; i < rowsTotal; i++){
        for (int k = 0; k < columnsTotal; k++){
```

> //There error in if condition. If your choice is 1. It will run this
> if condition 'mazeStructure[vxTemp][vyTemp-1].equals("!")'. As vyTemp
> = 0. vyTemp -1 < 0. Which will java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

```
 if (mazeStructure[vxTemp][vyTemp-1].equals("!") == false && mazeStructure[i][k].equals(mazeStructure[vxTemp][vyTemp])){
                    mazeStructure[vxTemp][vyTemp] = ".";
                    mazeStructure[vxTemp][vyTemp-1] = "P";
                    mazeStructure[vxTemp][vyTemp] = mazeStructure[i][k-1];
       }else if (mazeStructure[vxTemp][vyTemp-1] == "!"){
                    System.out.println("Move isn't allowed.");
       }else {
        continue;}
```